# WPF : remove item from listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF ListBox: Item Removal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378099/wpf-listbox-item-removal)

I am facing a really strange problem here.
What i am trying to do is just removing items from listbox in WPF , so here is the code :

```
    private void button9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox7.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string item in listBox7.SelectedItems)
            {
                listBox7.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

And that is not working at all , i always get error message [At the foreach loop] :

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

Which is really annoying because i have been using that method for years.
By the way i am fresh with WPF but i have a solid experience with C# so that should be okay for me.

EDIT :
Well , i have figured out that i was talking about something else when i typed "using it for years"

Anyway here is the fix :

```
        List<string> removals = new List<string>();

        foreach (string item in listBox7.SelectedItems)
        {
            removals.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (string s in removals)
        {
            listBox7.Items.Remove(s);
        }
```

Comment: How about searching for the error message before asking a question?

Comment: Do not know a lot about WPF but here is a link that might help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378099/wpf-listbox-item-removal

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times on SO.  Please search before asking a question.

Comment: That solution is kind of redundant, just use `listBox7.SelectedItems.`[`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) or (`ToList()`) in the foreach.

Comment: Ideally in WPF you should use data binding instead of manually adding or removing items directly on the ListBox. It takes a while to adjust to data binding and XAML/WPF, but it is quite nice once you get used to it. In that scenario, you would use an ObservableCollection<string> (or preferably the class with the display values for the ListBox) instead. Here is one article on data binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> i have been using that method for years

I doubt that, you can never modify the collection you loop over with `foreach`. Either loop over a copy or use `for`.

(`SelectedItems` is a subset of `Items`, if you modify `Items` you modify `SelectedItems`)

Comment: Better try it first on C# application and then edit your comment because you are wrong.

Comment: no he's not wrong. you *can not* modify a collection if you iterate over it with a foreach loop. That's even the error you get.

Comment: Okay it appears that i was wrong , anyway sorry for that.
I found a fix.