# Adding an Item to ItemsSource from a control

Tags: wpf

A control has an ItemsSource Property of type IEnumerable. If I try to add items to Items collection when ItemsSource is set I get an error "Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."

A method for Removing Items is present here:
[WPF - Best way to remove an item from the ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271576/wpf-best-way-to-remove-an-item-from-the-itemssource/3271762#3271762)

However I cannot find a method to (based on the same interface) to add a new Item. The AddNew method does not take any arguments. From the sample at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditablecollectionview.canaddnew.aspx I felt this to be the correct code:

```
IEditableCollectionView items = paneToDropInto.Items;
                if (items.CanAddNew)
                {
                    object newitem = items.AddNew();
                    newitem = contentToTransfer;
                    items.CommitNew();                    
                }
```

However it does not work. It does add the new item. But it is a blank Item. Note contentToTransfer.

Comment: what datatype/object is contentToTransfer?

Comment: What is contentToTransfer? Looks to me like you're just rereferencing the newitem variable, and you're actually comitting nothing at all?

Comment: i agree with tom, your binding to a blank new item...

Comment: It is a class. So I guess I need to copy properties from contentToTransfer one by one to newitem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. As pointed out by Tom and Djerry +1 both (thanks). I am just re referencing the new item which will not cause the original new item generated by AddNew to be saved (very stupid of me).

However there is another interface I can use (and did use):

```
IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem items = paneToDropInto.Items;
if (items.CanAddNewItem)
{
    object newitem = items.AddNewItem(contentToTransfer);                    
}
```